# Adding column names and values to statistic output in Python?

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, pandas

**Background:**

I'm currently developing some data profiling in SQL Server. This consists of calculating aggregate statistics on the values in targeted columns.

I'm using SQL for most of the heavy lifting, but calling Python for some of the statistics that SQL is poor at calculating. I'm leveraging the Pandas package through SQL Server Machine Language Services.

However,
I'm currently developing this script on Visual Studio. The SQL portion is irrelevant other than as background.

**Problem:**

My issue is that when I call one of the Python statistics functions, it produces the output as a series with the labels seemingly not part of the data. I cannot access the labels at all. I need the values of these labels, and I need to normalize the data and insert a column with static values describing which calculation was performed on that row.

**Constraints:**

I will need to normalize each statistic so I can union the datasets and pass the values back to SQL for further processing. All output needs to accept dynamic schemas, so no hardcoding labels etc.

**Attempted solutions:**

I've tried explicitly coercing output to dataframes. This just results in a series with label "0".

I've also tried adding static values to the columns. This just adds the target column name as one of the inaccessible labels, and the intended static value as part of the series.

I've searched many times for a solution, and couldn't find anything relevant to the problem.

Code and results below. Using the iris dataset as an example.

```
###########################
##    AGG STATS TEST SCRIPT
##
###########################

#LOAD MODULES
import pandas as pds

#GET SAMPLE DATASET
iris = pds.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/iris.csv')

#CENTRAL TENDENCY
mode1 = iris.mode()
stat_mode = pds.melt(
    mode1
    )

stat_median = iris.median()
stat_median['STAT_NAME'] = 'STAT_MEDIAN'   #Try to add a column with the value 'STAT_MEDIAN'

#AGGREGATE STATS
stat_describe = iris.describe()

#PRINT RESULTS
print(iris)
print(stat_median)
print(stat_describe)
```

```
###########################
##    OUTPUT
##
###########################

>>> #PRINT RESULTS
... print(iris)    #ORIGINAL DATASET
... 
     sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width    species
0             5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2     setosa
1             4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2     setosa
2             4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2     setosa
3             4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2     setosa
4             5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2     setosa
..            ...          ...           ...          ...        ...
145           6.7          3.0           5.2          2.3  virginica
146           6.3          2.5           5.0          1.9  virginica
147           6.5          3.0           5.2          2.0  virginica
148           6.2          3.4           5.4          2.3  virginica
149           5.9          3.0           5.1          1.8  virginica

[150 rows x 5 columns]
>>> print(stat_median)    #YOU CAN SEE THAT IT INSERTED COLUMN INTO ROW LABELS, VALUE INTO RESULTS SERIES
sepal_length            5.8
sepal_width               3
petal_length           4.35
petal_width             1.3
STAT_NAME       STAT_MEDIAN
dtype: object
>>> print(stat_describe)    #BASIC DESCRIPTIVE STATS, NEED TO LABEL THE STATISTIC NAMES TO UNPIVOT THIS
       sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width
count    150.000000   150.000000    150.000000   150.000000
mean       5.843333     3.057333      3.758000     1.199333
std        0.828066     0.435866      1.765298     0.762238
min        4.300000     2.000000      1.000000     0.100000
25%        5.100000     2.800000      1.600000     0.300000
50%        5.800000     3.000000      4.350000     1.300000
75%        6.400000     3.300000      5.100000     1.800000
max        7.900000     4.400000      6.900000     2.500000
>>>
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. There's a function called reset_index that will convert the index to a column, and create a new numerical index.

```
stat_median = pds.DataFrame(stat_median)
stat_median.reset_index(inplace=True)
stat_median = stat_median.rename(columns={'index' : 'fieldname', 0: 'value'})
stat_median['stat_name'] = 'median'
```